# Fortification enhancement vs a confirmed critical sneak attack

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor, sneak-attack, critical-hit

If a creature wearing an armor with [the fortification enhancement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/fortification/) is struck with a sneak attack that was a confirmed critical, does the PC roll percentile dice to resist for both critical and sneak attack or roll for them separately?

Answer (score 4):

Roll Separately.

full rules for [Fortification](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/fortification/):

> This suit of armor or shield produces a magical force that protects vital areas of the wearer more effectively. When a critical hit or sneak attack is scored on the wearer, there is a chance that the critical hit or sneak attack is negated and damage is instead rolled normally. The chance is 25% for light fortification, 50% for moderate fortification, and 75% for heavy fortification.

It triggers for each critical hit and for each sneak attack. Nothing suggests that critical hit and sneak attack should be merged as one event if it occurs on the same attack.